# Spring security : remember user who are already authenticated and don't redirect them to login form

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a project and trying to implement spring security in my spring mvc project.

The problem that I am facing is that for "chatbox/chatbox" url, user is getting redirected to login form even if he is authenticated.

What I have found is that: for the first time when user is hitting "/chatbox/chatbox" url then it is getting redirected to login page which is obvious as  per the code. After giving username and password and execution is going in "login" method of login controller and there after checking the credentials when line "redirect:/chatBox/chatBox" is excecuted, then it is again redirecting user to login page even if the user is authenticated.

Can anyone please help me what I missing here and doing wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Below is my code :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();          

        http.authorizeRequests()
       .antMatchers("/resources/**"
               ,"/chatBox/chat-websocket/"
               ,"/chatBox/chat-websocket/**"
               ,"chatBox/chat-websocket/").permitAll();


        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/chatBox/chatBox")
        .authenticated()
         .and()
         .formLogin().loginPage("/login/login").and().httpBasic();

    }
```

In login controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/userLogin")
    public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute UserProfile userProfile,HttpServletRequest request) { 

        UserProfile loggedinUser = userService.findUserByUsername(userProfile.getUsername());

        String passwordSha256Hex = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(userProfile.getPassword());

        boolean isMatched = userService.checkCredentials(userProfile.getUsername(), passwordSha256Hex);

        if(isMatched) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("username", userProfile.getUsername());
            session.setAttribute("firstName", loggedinUser.getFirstName());
            session.setAttribute("lastName",loggedinUser.getLastName());

            session.setAttribute("isAdmin", loggedinUser.getIsAdmin());

            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/chatBox/chatBox"); 
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("credentials not matched");
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:LoginAndRegister/LoginAndRegister"); 
        }

    }
```

Login.jsp

```
<form:form id="login-form" action="${userLoginUrl}" modelAttribute="userProfile" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <form:input type="text" path="username" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form:input type="password" path="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>

    <div>
         <label id="login-message" class="text-danger"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                     <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring security then why don't you let spring only handle everything for you which is more reliable and efficient.submit the form using spring security form and that will handle everything for you.

Doing something manually doesnt make sense when we have already predefined ways to do that.

Have a look at http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I will try to do as mentioned in the article.

Comment: sure..let me know if you face any issue while implementing that article.

Comment: I implemented as mentioned in the article, and learned that it is very tough to custom implement spring security in the project. We should let spring handle everything for us.